# Why can't I access the other variables I have in my other scripts, despite making them public?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so that I can access a public GameObject from one script. However, I get the error saying that the name of the variable does not exist in the current context.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 3.5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, -2, 0);
        gameObject.tag = "Player";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CalculateMovement();
    }

    void CalculateMovement()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * verticalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "Archer")
        {
            archerScore += 1;
        }
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);

    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ArcherCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject archerScore;
    public static int theScore;

    void Update()
    {
        archerScore.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Archers:" + archerScore;
    }
}
```

Basically, I get the error message that "the name 'Archer score' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: There are multiple issues but let's start with the simplest one - you have no numeric field / variable called `archerScore`.

Comment: Can you edit the error message into your code?

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to increase the "archery score" in the player, since it is an object, maybe you wanted to increase the "theScore" which is an integer.
But even if you were making the correct variables it wouldn't work because the increment of the variable inside the player has no relation to the other script.

instead of creating a static variable, you can create an instance of the script to access it.

into the script ArcherCounter do this:

public static ArcherCounter archerCounter;

Then, create an awake function to ensure that only one instance will be created:

```
void Awake() 
{
    if(archerCounter == null)
        archerCounter = this;
}
```

So you can access ArcherCounter variables in other scripts by doing this:

In Player.cs,

ArcherCounter.archerCounter.theScore += 1;

I hope I have helped and been clear.